# Invalid dotnet Certificate

Tags: visual-studio, ssl-certificate, window

at our company the Devs do not have local admin access. we have our domain user ad\user and for running things in admin mode we have to use the admin user created for us .\l-user.  To do any work we need to run in admin mode as .\l-user for each application. Because of this when pressing debug it starts up chrome as ad\user. the certificate is marked not valid.  If I open chrome separately as the admin user .\l-user it is marked as trusted.
I tried to fix it by

1. making sure to delete all certificates .
2. Exporting the certificate root ca issued by localhost to ad\user
   When tring it again, no luck. I am not sure how to get it to work.